# Alternatives to For/Do Loop to optimize indexing Matrix

Tags: performance-tuning, parallelization, functional-style

I am trying to optimize my code that searches for elements in the rows of matrix that are greater than 0. Then use that position to grab the element from other matrix. I use the do loop to iterate through each row. Then have another function that creates a new vector to replace that row of the vector. I have read these two questions on stackexchange ([Question 1](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/21135/how-to-transform-do-loop-to-more-efficient-codes),[Question 2](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18393/what-are-the-most-common-pitfalls-awaiting-new-users/18396#18396)) that say to use Map, Scan or NestList instead of for loops, but I am having difficulty applying it to my program. Any suggestions on how to speed this up would be greatly appreciated.

These are my function to search the matrix

```
positionAB = Function[{dataM, AB, row}, AB[[Flatten[Position[
            dataM[[All, row]], x : _ /; x > 0]]]]];


Rij = Function[{dataM, row}, dataM[[Flatten[Position[dataM[[All, row]], 
      x : _ /; x > 0]], row]]];


randomnFunction=Function[{x,y},(x.y)^2]
```

My loop is

```
indexM[data0_, initA0_, initB0_] := Block[

      {initA = initA0,
       initB = initB0,
       data = data0,
       iA0, iB0, iAB, id, ir},
       iA0 = initA;
       iB0 = initB;
       id = data;

         Do[

           iAB = positionAB[id, iA0, m];
           ir = Rij[id, m];
           ii=randomFunction[ir,iAB];
           iB0[[m]]=ii;,

               {m, 0, Length[iB0]}

           ];
 ]
```

Everyone says not to use for loops, which is what I originally had so switch to a Do but it has the exact same time to evaluate. Not sure how to use the suggestion in ([Question 1](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/21135/how-to-transform-do-loop-to-more-efficient-codes),[Question 2](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18393/what-are-the-most-common-pitfalls-awaiting-new-users/18396#18396)) for my iteration. Any advice would be greatly appreciated. I have many other numerical iterations using Euler's Algorithm that I have the same issue with.

It pretty large matrices. I have

```
dataM = RandomInteger[{0, 10}, {2000, 3000}];
iA = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {2000, 10}];
iB = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {3000, 10}];
```

So i have

```
 indexM[dataM,iA,iB]//AbsoluteTiming
```

Which for each iteration of m creates a 1x10 array. So after the loop the row of iB0 i.e. `iB0[[m]]` will be update with the new vector.

Update: I have tried to do the same thing as [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/22413/programming-a-numerical-method-in-the-functional-style) numerical method on stack exchange but doesn't help with my row replacement. I have tried MarcoB's suggestion but has gotten very convoluted to to the dot product and of the ir and iAB which is a giant array of arrays of different sizes. Ill update my code i have tried with that soon.

I also tried to use `ParallelDo` but doesn't update my iB0 unless I use `SetSharedVariable` which makes the computation time longer than my original. Any suggestions to get `ParallelDo` to work if i can't use Functional methods?

Update: MarcoB method

```
dataMatrix = RandomInteger[{0, 2}, {3, 4}];
iA = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {3, 2}];
iB = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {4, 2}];

positions = Position[dataMatrix, _?(# > 0 &)]
c = SortBy[GatherBy[positions, Last], Last@*Last][[;; , ;; , 1]]
rij = Select[DeleteCases[0] /@ Transpose[dataMatrix], UnsameQ[#, {}] &]
f = Function[{n, m}, n.m];

AB = Map[(iB[[#, All]]) &, c]
MapThread[f, {rij, AB}]
```

So I have gotten this but still have trouble dealing with a column that has all zeros.

Update:
In some good news if I can over come the zero elements it takes the time down from 69.1293 to 36.64. Not great but something!!! Open for any suggestions!!!

Comment: Have you considered using `Pick`? You give it two arrays of the same size, and it picks elements out of the first one corresponding to elements in the second which are `True`. It's not super clear to me what you're doing, but that may be useful.

Comment: Can you... explain what you're doing, exactly? Conceptually, I mean. Give us a smaller toy example with an input, an explanation of what you want, and an expected output.

Comment: I added all the parameters to run it now. For a better toy model you can scale them down. What i am trying to to is say dataM is a (10x20) iA (10x10) and iB is (20x10) matrix then i wanna iterate through each row so for m=1 we would have `positionAB[dataM,iA,1]` which is a (9x10) and have `Rij[dataM,1]` which is a (1x9) matrix then wanna take the dot product of `Rij.postionAB` to get (1x10) matrix and i wanna store this (1x10) matrix in an array where it will be the m entry. And repeat for m iterations.

Comment: I have also tried to use `ParalleleDo` but then i have to use `SetSharedVariable` otherwise it doesn't update `iB0[[m]]` which makes it even longer

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may be going to too much trouble here. Consider that `Position` works on a matrix just as well as a vector.

You did not include values for your parameters, so I can't use your code, but take a look at the following example. I have a matrix `selector` that contains $0$ or $1$ entries, and I want to grab the elements of another matrix `target` that correspond to $1$ elements in the first matrix.

```
SeedRandom[2016]
selector = RandomChoice[{0, 1}, {10, 10}];
target = RandomInteger[{100, 200}, {10, 10}];

positions = Position[selector, _?Positive]
Extract[target, positions]
```

This is quite similar to the functionality of [`Pick`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Pick.html), which you may also be interested in.

Comment: One could of course use `Positive[]`.

Comment: @J.M. One certainly could, and in fact it may even be better than the explicit test, in that `Positive` returns False when its input is a complex number, instead of failing and returning unevaluated. My (admittedly inconsequential) gripe with it is that I wish it had been named `PositiveQ`, rather than just Positive, to fall in line with other predicates such as `NumericQ`, `MatrixQ`, `VectorQ`, etc. Oh well. In any case, I amended my answer.

Comment: Ah, I'll have to differ with you on that. `Positive[]` is set *not* to evaluate unless its argument is numeric (satisfies `NumericQ[]`); this allows it to be used in assumptions (e.g. `Simplify[Abs[x], Positive[x]]`) among other things. (The behavior is similar to that of the relational operators.) "Query" functions, by way of contrast, are designed never to remain unevaluated. Were there such a thing as `PositiveQ[]`, `PositiveQ[x]` will return `False` at once, which may or may not be desired. (Similar arguments for `NonNegative[]`, `Negative[]`, `NonPositive[]` apply.)

Comment: @J.M. Ha! That's an excellent point I had not considered. Thank you for pointing that out!